# Is there a CSS way to make class="active" toggle on menu?

Tags: css

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/WZ6cqCcXaLuOCXnZdCa6?p=preview

Is there a CSS way so that when I click on `One` or `Two`, it becomes `class="active"` for `One` or `Two` and removed from `Home`?

Comment: No way to do it in CSS. I think you'll have to look into Javascript and DOM onclick event.

Comment: I've shown an example below that uses just CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can highlight each link with CSS alone, but not by using classes. Rather, use the `:target` pseudo class: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/kqoma

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul, li, div {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 10px;
}

li {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #08c;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

li a:hover, li a:target {
    background: #08c; 
    color: white;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello <code>:target</code>!</h1>

<div class="header">   
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">   
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#home" id="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#one" id="one">One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#two" id="two">Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, do in general you put text color of `link a` to `#08c` and when someone hovers or clicks `link a` you set the `color` of `link a` to `white` and background color of `link a` to `#08c`? right?

Comment: Yes, although on reflection, I'm not sure how useful a setup like this would be. Again, what do you need this for?

Comment: Consider that when user clicks on `Transaction` a new view appears with 3 links `current`, `recent` and `other`. The idea is when first clicked `current` should be selected and then on further user interaction other links might get selected. Hope that gives some context

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the html somehow, css doens't have the ability to change an elements class. You could write a little function to js to do this on a click event and remove the class from the old menu item and add it to the newly selected menu item.

like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6B5v2KrZonuI33dJySS6?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can so this with jQuery, following this format:

```
       switch (window.location.pathname) {
            case '/THE_URL_HERE':
               $('.nav-home').addClass('active');
               break;
            case '//THE_URL_HERE':
               $('.nav-one').addClass('active');
               break;
            case '//THE_URL_HERE':
               $('.nav-two').addClass('active');
               break;
        }
```

And add classes to your HTML:

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-home">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-one"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li class="nav-two"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using CSS exclusively. Behavioral features, such as linking, and modification of the DOM are outside the scope of CSS.

However, you could construct the links to modify the query string of the URL (e.g. ?item=one) and use the resulting GET values to set classes on your navigation.

Or use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use :target it's more flexible if it's to make a menu without javascript